# Couchdb Replication Notifications on Android Emulator

Tags: android

I am new to android development.
I tried to use couchdb on android emulator.
I was installed and used successfully in android emulator.

Now my scenario is,

I am able to do replication process in android emulator couchdb, it is replicated in remote couchdb database. i was done the same replication from remote database to emulator database, it works fine, the couch database replicated.

My question is how to display the notification in android emulator when the couchdb database updated from the remote couchdb.
(means updating the database in android couchdb from the remote couchdb, at the time of updating how to display the notification in android emulator?)

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can watch a database for changes using the _changes feed, see
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html